# AWS EC2 and storage spreadsheets

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does anyone know of a way to obtain the raw pricing data from AWS for their various hardware components (specifically EC2 and S3)? I noticed they produced a spreadsheet back in 2010 that isn't current. I haven't found any other up-to-date online resources.

I do realize they have web apps to role up stats. I need to do my own role-ups in Excel. Having the raw data would be very helpful.

Maybe someone has written a script to scrape their pricing pages?

Comment: You don't even have to scrape the pricing pages and don't need much in the way of a tool. Look at the source of the pricing pages.  They're programmatically fetching JavaScript data files of pricing data from a static source, and they're easily parsed.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for - I think it would be helpful to anyone else trying to find aggregated AWS information since the AWS pricing pages is difficult to read in a "raw" format http://www.ec2instances.info/

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% what you are after but you should look at Ice.

[image]

https://github.com/Netflix/ice

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need the raw pricing info in Excel.